# Can I ask a question based on interpersonal relationships?

Tags: support

I have a question that's pressing me a lot. It's related to my bff and his gf and should I tell him that she's cheating on me, etc etc...

Does this come under the purview of  'interpersonal skills'? If not which stack exchange do you recommend?

Comment: Please see the duplicate question's answers for information on our current policy. If you ask your question and it is closed, feel free to edit this question to discuss how to improve or bring it to be on topic and flag to reopen it.

Comment: @Catija hmm.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes it comes absolutely under Interpersonal Skills. It is just the type of question that addresses real-life interpersonal situations. So go ahead and ask your question on the main site www.interpersonal.stackexchange.com